# PHP variables disappearing in mkdir directory path

Tags: php, variables, path, directory, mkdir

I seem to be having an issue with using variables to create directories via the mkdir() function.  The variable is being parsed from the URL. See my coding below:

```
$pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
 $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
} else {
$pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
}
$pageURL;
$url = $pageURL;
$parse = parse_url($url);
$dirID = $parse['query'];
```

I'm using define() to define the folder path since the path is used several times throughout the code:

```
 define("DESTINATION_FOLDER", "mydir/".$dirID."/");
```

And here is the if statement telling it to create the directory if it doesn't exist:

```
if (!@file_exists(DESTINATION_FOLDER)) {      
    mkdir(DESTINATION_FOLDER);
}
```

Sounds pretty straightforward but for some reason the variable $dirID does not get read, and the file instead uploads to the mydir directory.  What's really odd, is that if I hardcode the variable to something like $dirID = "28", it works and the file gets uploaded like mydir/28/file.jpg.  I have used this method to pass variables many times before, but never to pass a variable to be used in the mkdir function.  Does anyone know what might be going on?

Thank you in advance for any and all help.

Comment: Instead of `$dirID = $parse['query'];`, have you tried `$dirID = $_GET['query'];` ?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention I have tried both GET and POST methods as well.  It still seems to just disappear.

Comment: I can't see anywhere in your code where `$pageURL` is assigned anything that looks like a query so why would you expect to find one via `parse_url()`?

Comment: To expand on what Phil said, you are building a URL that you parse but the URL has no query string.  What about `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`?  What is the query string supposed to look like (?123, or ?dirId=123)?

Comment: Thanks for all the responses so far...and I apologize if I'm a bit slow on following.  Would any of that matter if it shows the correct variable when I simply put in a echo $dirID; ?  Not in the mkdir folder path of course, but just somewhere random on that page for testing.
Also, the variable being passed would look more like '?28'

Comment: @drew010 I tried using $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], and while it displayed the correct variable in an echo statement, it once again went invisible when running the mkdir function.  I have no clue what is causing this.

Comment: @JasonRaines and what does `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` actually display when you echo it?  Is it possible mkdir is failing and returning false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all in the comments above, but I'll spell it out:

The query part is never actually passed to URL, and therefore not passed into "parse".

I'll paraphrase your code:

1. Construct URL using protocal (http/https) and server name and URL. (Note - you're not appending the query at this point)
2. Parse the url (which does not include the query)
3. Get the query from the parse (which still isn't there)

$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] is the bit you're looking for - you can either add to the URL and then parse, or just use it directly

```
$dirID = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

---

But why you'd use that to create the directory is a bit (A LOT) dangerous as it'll invariably contain invalid parameters. As suggested in the comments, you probably mean to get a particular value for a query string parameter? Or is it the actual string. You can get these from:

```
// For ?DirectoryName
$aKeys = array_keys($_GET)
$directoryName = isset($aKeys[0]) ? $aKeys[0] : '';
```

or

```
// For ?ParamName=DirectoryName
$directoryName = $_GET['ParamName']
```

I then also suggest you use a preg_match to validate the directory name meets an acceptable format and to avoid crap being created!

Comment: Thanks Robbie, but this still does not work.  Forgive me, you may have to 'spell things out' for me once in a while as I am becoming familiar with programming myself. You say that the query is never passed to the URL when in fact it is. It is passed from the previous page in the link.  i.e. http://www.example.com?28.  If I echo the variable, it will display exactly what is passed in the link '28'. Also, I just tried using $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] and once again the variable was correct if I echo'ed it, but disappeared when trying to create a directory. Either way, thanks for your help.

Comment: In which case, more code is required between the snippets you've posted as something else is wrong. Basically $dirID is not "in scope" - you either create this in a function and do not pass it back to where it's called, or you call the "define" in a function and do nto pass $dirID into that function.

Comment: Funny thing is, if I hardcode the variable to something like $dirID = "28";, everything works fine.  Problem is I need it to stay dynamic as it's pulling a unique variable to help keep the files organized in specific directories.  Thanks for your help Robbie.